# parsing a multi leve json file in Go Language

Tags: parsing, go, multi-level

I need to parse and get values from fields in a json file.

```
[{"id": 27}, {"id": 0, "label": "Label 0"}, null, {"id": 93}, {"id": 85}, {"id": 54}, null, {"id": 46, "label": "Label 46"}]}}
```

Though i can work on single level , i am at a loss how i can iterate through levels here.
I have tried looking for an answer in google , various help sites and even stackoverflow.
I could not find any example that might help me in working with multi level json byte array.
Hope somebody can lead me to understand and work on it.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Please define what you need better. In general, the best practice is to map your json to strict data types, and then it will be easy to do.

Answer (score 4):

Just parse the JSON into an array of structs:

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
)

type Item struct {
    Id    int
    Label string
}

func main() {

    data := []byte(`[{"id": 27}, {"id": 0, "label": "Label 0"}, null, {"id": 93}, {"id": 85}, {"id": 54}, null, {"id": 46, "label": "Label 46"}]`)
    var val []*Item

    if err := json.Unmarshal(data, &val); err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("Error: %s\n", val)
        return
    }

    for _, it := range val {
        fmt.Printf("%#v\n", it)
    }

}
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Can you explain why you need a pointer to the Item struct when you initialized: var val []*Item?

Comment: I used the pointer to reflect the 'null' entries in the JSON. This way marshal just inserts a 'nil' into the slice instead of an Item{0,""}.